# Shiny: BigQuery Fails when user selects "All" value

Tags: r, shiny, google-bigquery

I am trying to use a BigQuery query to populate plots in Shiny.  The query includes input values from the ui using selectInput.  If the user selects a value that exists in the DB, such as year is 2014, the query works correctly, however, I would like the user to also be able to select "All."  "All" should be a selection of all values, however, I am not sure how to express that in the query using selectInput.

**server.r**

```
data1 <- eventReactive(input$do_sql, {
bqr_auth(token = NULL, new_user = FALSE, verbose = FALSE)

query = paste('select month, event, partner_name, sum(f0_) from [dataset.table] where year =',input$year1,' and partner_name = \"',input$partner_name,'\"
              GROUP by 1,2,3
              ORDER by 1 asc
              LIMIT 10000', sep="")

bqr_query(projectId, datasetId, query, maxResults =2000)
})
```

**ui.r**

```
 ( 
  selectInput("year1", 
              "Year:", 
              c("All",2014,2015
                ))
),

 (
  selectInput("partner_name", 
              "Partner:", 
              c("All", 
                unique(as.character(data5$partner_name))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should slightly change the query you are constructing
So, currently you have

```
SELECT month, event, partner_name, SUM(f0_) 
FROM [dataset.table] 
WHERE year = selected_year
AND partner_name = "selected_partner_name"
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1 ASC
LIMIT 10000
```

with respectively:

```
selected_year --> input$year1
selected_partner_name --> input$partner_name
```

Instead, you should construct below query

```
SELECT month, event, partner_name, SUM(f0_) 
FROM [dataset.table] 
WHERE (year = selected_year OR "selected_year" = "All") 
AND (partner_name = "selected_partner_name" OR "selected_partner_name" = "All")
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1 ASC
LIMIT 10000
```

> I am not shiny user at all - so excuse my syntax - below is just my
>   guess with regard of implementing above suggestion

```
query = paste('SELECT month, event, partner_name, sum(f0_) 
    FROM [dataset.table] 
    WHERE (year =',input$year1,' OR "All" ="',input$year1,'") 
    AND (partner_name = \"',input$partner_name,'\" OR "All" = \"',input$partner_name,'\")
          GROUP by 1,2,3
          ORDER by 1 asc
          LIMIT 10000', sep="")
```

Comment: I don't understand.  How will the server file send the correct input to the query if I've removed the input parameter and what is "selected_partner_name"?

Also, I'd have to send a string to the query for year when year is a integer.  This will cause the query to fail.

Comment: you still need to use parameters. I just fixed the query that you need to build/construct using shiny syntax and parameters

Answer (score 0):

Mikhail's solution worked perfectly for character variables, but numerics didn't work correctly.  I decided to use a character date range instead of the year numeric I originally used.  Thanks.